# Please help on query for sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select 
u.username 
from users u join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
where  username in
                    ( 
                        select 
                            username 
                            from users u join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
                            join roles r on ur.roleid=r.roleid 
                            where r.active=1 
                            and u.active=1 
                            and ur.active=1 
                            and ur.roleid in (1,2,3,4)
                    )
r.active=1 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1
```

User id have different roles in the the user roles table need the userid assign the roleid 1,2,3,4

For example user A have 1,2,3,4,5,100 roles it should not display only user have assigned 1,2,3,4.

Comment: you mean display all userid except 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: no i need userids which is assigned only 1,2,3,4

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains phrase "very urgent please" - and author has no clue about what he's asking.

Comment: I can't quite understand what the question is, even though there is an answer below, so I am recommending deletion at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution, though this is a heavy query but I can find only the following solution

```
select distinct(u.username) 
from 
users u
join 
userrole ur 
on 
u.userid= ur.userid 
join
roles r
on
ur.roleid=r.roleid
where  
r.active=1 
and 
u.active=1 
and 
ur.active=1 
and 
ur.userid in (select userid from userrole where roleid = 1)
and ur.userid in (select userid from userrole where roleid = 2)
and ur.userid in (select userid from userrole where roleid = 3)
and ur.userid in (select userid from userrole where roleid = 4)
```

**you can see the working solution at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25dd8/1**

user table

[image]

userrole table

[image]

roles table

[image]

**OUTPUT OF QUERY**

[image]

Comment: it is not working  it throws an exception Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: ahh sorry fixed the query

Comment: select username from users u
        join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
        join roles r on ur.roleid=r.roleid where r.active=1 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1 and ur.roleid LIKE '1,2,3,4'   when i tried this it throws an error Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "us.roleid" could not be bound.

Comment: you cannot use `LIKE` here its not a sequence ?

Comment: Try adding a demo of your table structure at Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: can you try = instead of like, select u.username,ur.roleid from users u join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid join roles r on ur.roleid=r.roleid where r.active=1 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1 and ur.roleid = '1,2,3,4'

Comment: table users  userid, username ,active      table  userrole  user roleid userid roleid active  table roles roleid ,rolename

Comment: please check this Fiddle, is the structure correct? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1eb9/2 so we can correct the query

Comment: try this query select u.username from users u
join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
where  username in
(select username from users u
join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
 and u.active=1 
 and ur.active=1 and ur.roleid LIKE '1,2,3,4')
 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1

Comment: is this your structure, TABLE users(userid int, username varchar(255), active int)

TABLE userrole(userid int, roleid varchar(255), active  varchar(255))

TABLE roles(roleid int, rolename varchar(255), active int)

Comment: yes.........................................................

Comment: userrole table saves individual role id like (userid,role,active) (1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,1), i.e. individual role id for each user or like (1,'1,2,3,4',1) i.e. in one field, comma separated

Comment: it stores individual roles

Comment: that's why our query was not working, 2mins will edit it. also you want records that have all 4 id's assigned i.e. 1,2,3,4 or any one of 1,2,3,4

Comment: need all 4 ids assigned

Comment: please see the answer now, this query should be useful http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25dd8/1

Comment: it is not wrking it returns empty result set

Comment: does any user has all 4 id's? because it is working for us you can check it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25dd8/1

Answer (score 0):

`try this`

```
   select username from users u
                           inner join userrole ur on u.userid= ur.userid 
                           inner join roles r on ur.roleid=r.roleid 
where r.active=1 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1 and  r.active=1 and u.active=1 and ur.active=1 
and ur.roleid in ('1','2','3','4')
```

Comment: error message :Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "usr.roleid" could not be bound.

Comment: @user2996150 :: without proper db-shema its not possible to answer i'm jus guessing on query try it one last time!!

Comment: returns the results but not result was not correct